# What does `g_autoptr(MyApplication) app = my_application_new();` mean

Tags: c++, c, flutter

I was browsing through a flutter linux application source code and i hit a little snag understanding this method of declaration and if it's C or C++.

```
// Source code for context 
#include "my_application.h"
 
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  g_autoptr(MyApplication) app = my_application_new();
  return g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
}
```

I'm familiar with these declaration and assigning methods

```
structB->hb = 16;
// OR
structB.hb = 18;
// OR
int hb = 10; 
// And the other common method of declaration
```

But i have never seen this method of declaration and I really don't know what it means

```
g_autoptr(MyApplication) app = my_application_new();
```

Comment: Linux code is usually C. I don't know this lib, but it looks like a poor man's smart pointer or some such. Perhaps coded through a jungle of nasty macros. If you don't know what it means then read the documentation (easily found with a search engine) or failing that, the actual source code.

Comment: looks like it is initialization not assignment, but in presence of macros nothing is certain

Comment: g_autoptr is probably a macro. What is the definition of g_autoptr?

Comment: I searched for `g_autoptr(MyApplication) app = my_application_new();` before asking this question.

Comment: https://developer-old.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Macros.html#g-autoptr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, `g_autoptr` is a macro that declares a pointer to the specified type and registers a function that will delete object when the pointer goes out of scope.

In GCC, `g_autoptr` produces something like

```
__attribute__((cleanup(MyApplication::cleanup_func))) MyApplication *app = my_application_new();
```

Using this extension, the compiler can automatically detect when the pointer is no longer used and call the function that will free the object.

Please see https://blogs.gnome.org/desrt/2015/01/30/g_autoptr/ for more examples.